# Meaning of ひとつで自由に出せるように

Tags: translation, meaning

The sentence is:

> ギャンブラーを名乗るなら、采の目ぐらい、投げ方ひとつで自由に出せるようになっておけ.

MC is revealing a secret how to win every dice game. But I'm not sure the meaning of his words. Does it mean throwing dice one by one?

Comment: Your question is really about 「投げ方ひとつで」, not about 「ひとつで自由に出せるように」.  It is about the set phrase "Noun + ひとつ + で".

Answer (score 4):

ひとつ（で） actually applies to the previous word 投げ方 here. It's kind of like だけ in this usage; he is saying to become able to control the result of the dice *solely through just* the 投げ方 (way of throwing).

In the above sentence, the 投げ方 is described as the sole deciding factor for producing the result.

Wiktionary has a good example of the usage:

> ある物事を左右する要素。 (The factor that influences another event.)
>   君の返事**一つで**どうにでもなることだ。 *(All it would take is) the right reply from you and this could all go away.*

That's not to say that there aren't other ways the situation could be resolved, but a reply would serve on its own to decide things all by itself.

大辞林 also highlights its use in this kind of situation.

> ひとつ【LHL】  【一つ】
>   一
>   （ 名 ）
>   ⑥　そうすることによって決まる，それ次第であることを強調していうときに用いる。 「やるかやめるか決心**ひとつ**だ」 「心の持ちよう**ひとつで**どうにでも変わる」 (used to emphasize that sth *will be resolved/settled by doing X*; or *hinges on / is dependent on X*). "*To do it or not -- it is all a matter of how you will make up your mind.*" "*You can be whatever person you want to be; it all depends on your attitude.*"

大辞泉 is more plain about it and says not much more than だけ, but I get the impression that it's stronger than だけ and gives a greater sense of exclusion.

> ９ 名詞の下に付いて、それ以外にはないことを強調する語。…だけ。「身**ひとつで**脱出する」「母の手**ひとつで**育てられる」「行くか行かないかは自分の決心**ひとつ**だ」 (Following a noun, emphasizes that there is nothing else than that. ...*dake*.) "*Make it out using nothing more than one's own body*" "*Be raised solely by the hand of one's mother" "Whether to go or not entirely hinges on your own ability to decide*"

(translations are mine)